# Python group by 2 values under a column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate the maximun video viewed time according to the sum of the number of free and anonymous users views with data frame like below:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FpKOrObZQVQ3WjRVurpk8_wiY2A-uhQg?usp=sharing

I have problem with telling python to get free and anonymous users under column 'user_mode', code as below:

```
import pandas as pd

video = pd.read_csv('video_views.csv')
product = pd.read_csv('products.csv')

vv_with_product = pd.merge(video, product,
                           on = 'pd_id',
                           how = 'outer')
fuser = vv_with_product.groupby(['series_name', 'user_mode'])['vv_cnt'].sum()
order = fuser.sort_values()
print(order)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want combined data for the two user_mode values, a custom column can be made that checks if a user is anonymous or free and groups them as shown below:

```py
import pandas as pd

video = pd.read_csv('video_views.csv')
product = pd.read_csv('products.csv')

vv_with_product = pd.merge(video, product,
                           on = 'pd_id',
                           how = 'outer')
vv_with_product['user_mode'] = vv_with_product['user_mode'].apply(
                           lambda x: 'Free or Anonymous'
                           if x in ('Free', 'Anonymous') else x)
fuser = vv_with_product.groupby(['series_name', 'user_mode'])['vv_cnt'].sum()
order = fuser.sort_values()
print(order)
```

Comment: thank you, but if i only want the rows of Free or Anonymous, what can i do to exclude the rest?

Comment: You can index the columns for Free or Anonymous using `vv_with_product['Free or Anonymous']` or otherwise indexed as described in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)